Spence's signalling problem
My professor uploaded job market signalling question with the solution, but on the solution, I could not get some part, so I would like to get your help to understand it. First, I could not understand why did we say that $e_p \geq 1$ (I know that we found $e_p = 1$ by doing FOC). Secondly, when we look at the low type's deviation at $e = 0.5$, how was it derived? Thank you in advance.

